# Singleton Class which requires some async call

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a Singleton Class which loads some data on its construction. The problem is that loading this data requires calling `async` methods, but the constructor cannot be `async`.

In other words, my class has following structure:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() 
   {
       LoadData();
   }

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
       }
    }
}
```

`LoadData()` is an `async` function which calls lots of `async` functions as well as initialization.
How can I call `LoadData()` properly so everything initialize correctly?

Comment: Using Lazy<T> should do what you want.

Comment: you can also call a async method from a constructor.

Comment: Please give more context about what you want to happen. It's somewhat unclear at the moment.

Comment: @PeterRitchie How does `Lazy<T>` help here?  It doesn't provide any mechanism to wait on asynchronous operations...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Depends on what he's really trying to accomplish.  I've added an answer with details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The problem is that loading this data requires calling async methods, but the constructor cannot be async.

While you can't make the constructor itself asynchronous, you *can* call asynchronous methods from within the constructor.  You just will not get the results back immediately.

Provided the asynchronous methods return `Task` or `Task<T>`, you can always use a continuation on the task to set your data within the class once the asynchronous operation completes, or just block on the results, depending on what makes the most sense in your scenario.  Without knowing the requirements for construction of this object, it's difficult to know what is appropriate in this scenario.

---

Edit:

One option, given the goals listed above, would be to change your `Singleton` declaration so that method to retrieve the `Instance` was a method, not a property.  This would allow you to make it asynchronous:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() 
   {
          // Don't load the data here - will be called separately
   }

   public static async Task<Singleton> GetInstance()
   {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
            await instance.LoadData();
         }

         return instance;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to use `await` on the call to actually retrieve the instance.  The nice thing about this is that it does make it very clear that you're calling an asynchronous operation, and you will get proper handling of the results, as the result will come back like any other async method.

Be aware, however, that this isn't thread safe (though the original wasn't either), so if you're going to use this Singleton from multiple threads, you may have to rethink the overall design.

The other option would be to make your `Singleton` class not automatically load data.  Make the methods that retrieve the data from the class asynchronous, instead.  This provides some real advantages, as the usage is probably a bit more standard, and you can support calls from multiple threads a bit more easily (since you can control the data loading process) than you'd be able to handle it with making the access of the class instance asynchronous.

Comment: If you use double-check-locking, you're going to have a problem, since you can't use await inside of lock()

Answer (score 30):

The solution for a ***thread-safe, async singleton*** is actually super simple, if we only let the inner mechanisms of the `Task` class work for us!

So, how does a `Task` work? Let’s say you have an *instance* of a `Task<T>` and you `await` it once. Now the task is executed, and a value of `T` is produced and returned to you. What if you `await` the *same* task *instance* again? In this case the task just returns the previously produced value immediately in a completely synchronous manner.

And what if you `await` the same task instance *simultaneously* from multiple threads (where you would normally get a race condition)? Well, the first one (since there *will* be one that gets there first) will execute the task code while the others will wait for the result to be processed. Then when the result has been produced, all the `await`’s will finish (virtually) simultaneously and return the value.

So the solution for an `async` singleton that is thread-safe is actually super simple:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Task<Singleton> _getInstanceTask = CreateSingleton();

    public static Task<Singleton> Instance
    {
        get { return _getInstanceTask; }
    }

    private Singleton(SomeData someData)
    {
        SomeData = someData;
    }

    public SomeData SomeData { get; private set; }

    private static async Task<Singleton> CreateSingleton()
    {
        SomeData someData = await LoadData();
        return new Singleton(someData);
    }
}
```

Now you can access the singleton this way:

```
Singleton mySingleton = await Singleton.Instance;
```

or

```
Singleton mySingleton = Singleton.Instance.Result;
```

or

```
SomeData mySingletonData = (await Singleton.Instance).SomeData;
```

or

```
SomeData mySingletonData = Singleton.Instance.Result.SomeData;
```

Read more here: [Async singleton initialization](http://www.laserbrain.se/post/2015/11/22/async-singleton-initialization.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [asynchronous lazy initialization](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) for this:

```
public class Singleton
{
  private static readonly AsyncLazy<Singleton> instance =
      new AsyncLazy<Singleton>(CreateAndLoadData);

  private Singleton() 
  {
  }

  // This method could also be an async lambda passed to the AsyncLazy constructor.
  private static async Task<Singleton> CreateAndLoadData()
  {
    var ret = new Singleton();
    await ret.LoadDataAsync();
    return ret;
  }

  public static AsyncLazy<Singleton> Instance
  {
    get { return instance; }
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Singleton singleton = await Singleton.Instance;
```

One benefit of using `AsyncLazy<T>` is that it is threadsafe. However, be aware that it always executes its delegate on a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't make much sense that you want asynchronously initialize a singleton.  If you simply want to call an method that returns Task in your initialization, you can simply do:

```
var task = MyAsyncMethod();
task.Wait();
return task.Result;
```

Without the need to make the method `async`.

But, if what you want is for the singleton value to be a task, you can use Lazy as such:

```
Lazy<Task<int>> l = new Lazy<Task<int>>(async () => { int i = await calculateNumber(); return i; });
```

In addition, `Lazy<T>` is the preferred method for implementing "singletons".  Singleton classes are hard to get right (or hard to *keep* right)...